# Finding card from the deck of cards (ArrayList) and printing its index

Tags: java

Line 9 gives an error "**Incompatible Operand types String and card**". How do I find a card from the deck and print its index. I have a create method that creates a shuffled deck and stores the objects in the ArrayList (deck). Card is the class.

```
System.out.print("\nEnter Rank: "); 
int r3 = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("\nEnter Suit: "); 
int s3 = sc.nextInt();
Card c3 = new Card(r3, s3);
                            
for(int i=0; i<52; i++)
{ 
   if(Card.printCard(r3, s3)==Card.deck.get(i))
   {
      System.out.println("\nCard at position "+Card.deck.indexOf(c3));
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the conditional? You can't check if a card equals a string; they're not the same type.

Comment: I am trying to compare the ```printCard()``` function, which returns a string, to the elements in the deck arraylist. @Matt

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a `Card` to a `String`; that's like asking if a cow equals a watermelon.

You will instead need to compare the attributes of the chosen card to those of the card you're currently looking at. For instance, assuming your `Card` class has accessors for the suit and rank:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    Card card = Card.deck.get(i);
    if (card.getRank() == r3 && card.getSuit() == s3) {
        // System.out.println(...);
    }
}
```